# Quorum Tessera Private/Public Keys vs Quorum (Ethereum) Keystore - Difference and Keys Management

Tags: quorum

Understand that Quorum Tessera is for encryption, decryption, and distribution of private transactions while Quorum Keystore is for normal transaction signing. Can both be collapsed into one set of public/private keys?

Understand that Tessera can integrate with key vaults to secure the keys. Can Quorum keystores be protected in a similar way as well?

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they cannot be as they are completely different types of keys and their use is defined by the context they live in.